# s3 service using s3cmd tool through URL based firewalls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am behind a URL based application firewall and currently using s3cmd tool to access amazon's s3 service. Doing a bit of searching has asked me to whitelist s3.amazonaws.com but I see that s3cmd uses a custom URL which goes by s3://[bucket-name].

Would whitelisting amazonaws.com still work in this case or is there something else that would need to be whitelisted?

Answer (score 1):

Does your proxy accept wildcards?  You'll want to whitelist `*.s3.amazonaws.com` at least, and most likely `*.s3-*.amazonaws.com` if you point at region-specific endpoints.